# Variable referencing error: how do I make this work?

Tags: python, function, variables, reference, variable-assignment

Now I know about global declarations, and can also figure why an error is coming up (count is referenced in the function and I'm calling it later), but can't think of any way to circumvent it. Why is `count` giving an error even though I'm calling the function `f` after I define the variable? How can I rewrite this code snippet?
Thanks for the help!

```
def f(x):
    if count < x:
        <some irrelevvant code>

for i in range(10):
    count = 1
    f(3)
    <some more irrelevant code>
```

My apologies, I think my original question was kind of unclear. The "irrelevant code" I mentioned might actually be relevant, hence I'm uploading my entire code:

```
def ways(l, h):
    if count2 < h:
        for v in A:   #A is a globally defined list
            if u != v:
                if check(t, v):
                    count2 += 1
                    t = v
                    ways(l, h)
    else:
        count1 += 1

count1 = 0
for u in A:
    count2 = 1
    t = u
    ways(9, 3)
```

Now since I am recursively calling the function `ways`, I cannot have `count2` defined as a function argument in `ways`. `Count2` must be reset to 1 every time the `u` for loop runs, but not whenever `ways` is called.

Comment: You pass `count` into `f` explicitly.

Comment: in loop, + f(3, count)

Comment: You can do `count=1` before defining `f(x)`, it will work, but you sholdn't do that, better to pass `count` to `f` explicitly, since `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: @Darth Kotik:  YES!  Use the Zen of Python!

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x,count):
    if count < x:
        <some irrelevant code>

for i in range(10):
    count = 1
    f(3,count)
    <some more irrelevant code>
```

Make "count" local in the function.  If you pass *count* to function *f*, there's no need to make it global, and it should work just fine.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail in the question. I do not think this approach will work as the function is called recursively.